# auto increment not reset between insert into two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this script:

```
#create departments table
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`department_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#inserts - departments table
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Parks and recreation");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Portable immediate treatment");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Veterinary");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Gardening");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Business Registration");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Environment");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Sanitation");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("Recycling");
INSERT INTO `departments`(`department_name`)VALUES("all");

#create departments_in_langueage table
CREATE TABLE `departments_in_language` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `departments_in_language_department_id_idx` (`department_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `departments_in_language_department_id` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`department_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#inserts - departments_in_language table
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("1","hebrew","חזות העיר");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("2","hebrew","ניידת טיפול מיידי");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("3","hebrew","ווטרינריה");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("4","hebrew","גינון");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("5","hebrew","רישוי עסקים");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("6","hebrew","איכות הסביבה");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("7","hebrew","תברואה");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("8","hebrew","מיחזור");
INSERT INTO `departments_in_language`(`department_id`,`language`,`description`)VALUES("9","hebrew","כללי");
```

Departments_in_language have field named="department_id" (FOREIGN KEY).
The problem:
When I run this script, I got some Error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`teres`.`departments_in_language`, CONSTRAINT `departments_in_language_department_id` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`department_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO )
```

I saw that the Id's of department_in_language are not start from 1, 
It's mean that the counter of the "auto" not reset between the inserts;
And this is the cause of the Error.
What can I do?

Comment: in first table `AUTO INCREMENT` is set to 10 and you are trying to insert `department_id` as 1,2,3,4... which are not present in table first, try to set  `AUTO INCREMENT` to 1

Comment: yes I know, but I want to reset the auto...

Comment: if you wish to simply reset auto increment just alert your table `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: When I have create table without insert after, am I need change the auto field too?

Comment: Yes you can but I am not recommending to do this

Comment: Why? Do you have anothe way?

Comment: No, But why do  you wants to reset again it since there may be already data present with same ID this may cause other issue as well

Comment: Because I want to solve the error, the auto must start from 0 after one insert, do you understand the meaning of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your table creation query set `AUTO_INCREMENT` to 10 AND 9. It should set it to 1.

```
#create departments table
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  [...]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#create departments_in_langueage table
CREATE TABLE `departments_in_language` (
  [...]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: When I have create table without insert after, am I need change the auto field?

Comment: See my edit, I missed the `AUTO_INCREMENT` declaration in your table creation.